# How to use mongodb in a SvelteKit project?

Tags: sveltekit, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I imported mongodb with `import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';`, (version of mongodb is 4.0.0-beta.5) it works fine in `svelte-kit dev` and `svelte-kit preview`, but when I try to start the server with `node build`, it throws `Error: Dynamic require of "os" is not supported`. How can I configure sveltekit or vite to import mongodb in production?

Comment: That comment u added solved it? dont forget to mark as answered ;) - otherwise share you nodejs version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that since vite only precompiles packages in dependencies (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/162#issuecomment-629623566), mongodb should be in dependencies, not devDependencies.