# SvelteKit - MongoDB issue with import

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sveltekit

Iam having issue with importing MongoDB in production.

I already tried solution from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966257/how-to-use-mongodb-in-a-sveltekit-project).

Iam getting this error when visiting page with page.server.ts that use DB

```
Node.js v18.16.1
Error: open EEXIST
at new Socket (node:net:413:13)
at process.getStdin [as stdin] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:222:17)
at get (<anonymous>)
at getOwn (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:190:5)
at BuiltinModule.syncExports (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:314:31)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:294:17)
at BuiltinModule.getESMFacade (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:299:17)
at BuiltinModule.compileForPublicLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:277:10)
at loadBuiltinModule (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:56:9)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936:15) {
errno: -17,
code: 'EEXIST',
syscall: 'open'
}
node:internal/process/promises:288
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^
```

I tried to set everything same as in this [repo](https://github.com/stolinski/svelte-kit-mongodb-example).

My app starts with `node app.cjs` witch contains this:

```
async function loadApp() {
await import("./index.js");
}

loadApp();
```

and here is DB.ts

```
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb';
import { MONGO_URL } from '$env/static/private'; 

const client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL)

export function start_mongo() {
    console.log('Starting mongo...');
    return client.connect();
}

export default client.db()
```

I also tried to place it in src/lib/server, src/lib, and src.

Removing `import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb';` and page loads just fine.

**mongodb is not in devDependencies**

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE#1**

I have also contacted hosting support to see if they can help, and they think the problem is with using async.

"This is the CPU thread issue with Node.js on our server. We suggest you prevent the use of `async await` on the code to prevent further errors or breaks on the app."

But removing async did not help.

**UPDATE#2**

I tried to host my app somewhere else evennode and app works just fine.

Just addding import in any page.server.ts is causing this issue. It seems like just wierd combination of svelte + mongo + my hosting that is causing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with my hosting, they node server is weird.